# Boolean Intersect - Creating slices instead of solids

Tags: materials, modifiers, fluid-simulation

I am trying to fill a bottle with a liquid. I modeled the bottle (added solidy modifier) then duplicated, scaled down, and separated the new object (labeled: liquid). I added a plane and boolean intersect modifier to the liquid object but some sections render as slices instead of a full bottle.

Here is the error:
[image]
Here is what I am trying to get it to do:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Intersect mode in the Boolean Modifier, the result will be only the part that intersects with the target geometry, and since your target is a plane the result will be a 2D slice of the original model.

What you probably wants is use a cube instead of a plane, that way only and everything that is inside the cube will be visible:

[image: intersect with cube Boolean Modifier]

Comment: Thanks! Flipping the plane 180 degrees and changing the boolean back to difference ended up working.